# What are the differences between the C++ NaN and Armadillo NaN?

Tags: c++, nan, armadillo

The "C++ NaN" I'm talking about is the one that may be returned by [this cmath function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/nan-function/):

```
double nan (const char* tagp);
```

The "Armadillo NaN" is the one that is part of the [Armadillo linear algebra package](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#constants):

```
datum::nan      “not a number” (NaN); caveat: NaN is not equal to anything, even itself
```

Is it safe to mix them?

---

Thought exercise:

Say you have a function that finds and returns a value from an Armadillo matrix:

```
arma::mat lookup_table;
in a loop or something
double val = deriving_value_from_table(lookup_table, input1, input2, input3 ...)
```

Say the function determines that it should return `lookup_table(3, 2)`, and said value is `arma::datum::nan`.

Can I use `val` and expect it to be a proper NaN? What if I later put `val` into a different Armadillo matrix, will functions like `arma::is_finite(X)` still work as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NaN is a class of values of the underlying `double` implementation, which, on virtually any platform where `std::nan` is defined and Armadillo can run, will be the usual IEEE 754. Any quiet NaN is just as ugly as any other - i.e. they will all compare different than any value (including itself), and this is a thing that is handled in hardware, not by Armadillo or the standard library.

The only difference between what `std::nan` returns and the Armadillo NaNs may be that they can have a different underlying bit pattern - as there are many different values that are valid NaN. Still, it's a difference that would be visible only to code that examines explicitly the underlying bytes, so in numerical code should be completely irrelevant.